# SonataAdmin related entities get filtered out when configureQuery is used together with datagrid filters

Tags: sonata-admin

I have two entities - Category and Item. Category can have multiple Items. I've set up sonata admin for a Category and in list mapper I have "->add('items'). I also have datagridFilters for Category where I also have "->add('items'). Everything works well (I get a list of Categories and for each Category I get a comma separated list of Items. If I use filtering by Item, I find Category that contains that Item and it shows other Items in that Category as it is supposed to. However, if I add in configureQuery relation to items, and use filtering by Item as previously, all other Items related to Category are filtered out as well:

```
    protected function configureQuery(ProxyQueryInterface $query): ProxyQueryInterface
    {
        $query = parent::configureQuery($query);

        $rootAlias = current($query->getRootAliases());

        $query
            ->addSelect('i') 
            ->leftJoin($rootAlias . '.items', 'i')
        ;

        return $query;
    }
```

Is there any solution to overcome this behavior?

I've tried removing configureQuery and enabling it again and this is the cause of the issue. However, I need it so queries would be more efficient.